# Difference between JavaScript Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can someone enligten me on the difference between these two arrays in JavaScript ?

```
var a = {};
var b = [];
```

Comment: `b` actually is an array, while `a` isn't.

Comment: The first one is not an array, but an object.

Comment: @X.L.Ant Well `b` is also an object, really. ;)

Comment: @JohnWhite Did I say otherwise ?

Comment: See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals) for more details.

Comment: @X.L.Ant For some reason I read it as if you did (I know I just fired up some chit-chat before the post is deleted).

Comment: @JohnWhite Bous to liki dow moV pilon. Provide an example

Answer (score 2):

the first one  `var a = {};` is an object, it is associative ( a key with a value), you cannot put multiple same key.

```
 var a = { "name" : 'john', "lastname" : "shmit", "age" : 25 }
```

the second one  `var b = [];` is an array. not assocative and you can put anything you want inside ( other array or object ):

```
 var b = [ "orange" , "baanana" , "apple" , 1 , "555" ]
```

Comment: Thanks @Alainlb :) I am thankful that you dont vote the question down.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = {}; // Object
var b = []; // Array object
```

Comment: Can you provide an example ?

Comment: var a = {
   property1: value1,
   property2: value2
};
var b = [3, 4, 5];

Answer (score 0):

Object

```
var a = { key: 42};
```

Access is possible with key (a string) with dot notation `a.key` or bracket notation a['key']. In the last case, instead of the string `key`, a variable with the string can be used, like

```
prop = 'key'; 
alert(a[prop]);
```

Array

```
var b = [0, 0, 3];
```

Access is possible with an index (an positive integer) and bracket notation `a[2]`.

Other access is possible with

- [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach),
- [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every),
- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter),
- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight).